# (OpenGL) wglCreateContext() context's version

Tags: opengl

I want to know which version wglCreateContext() will return to me. Will it always returns the higher version available ? Do you have some official documentation links about that ?

Answer (score 5):

#### You need to use `wglCreatContextAttribsARB (...)` from the extension: [WGL_ARB_create_context](https://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/wgl_create_context.txt).

#### Something to the effect:

```c
    // Request an OpenGL 3.3 context
    const GLuint attribs [] = { WGL_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION_ARB, 3,
                                WGL_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION_ARB, 3,
                                0 };

    HGLRC hRC = wglCreateContextAttribsARB (hDC, 0, attribs);
```

Ironically, this means creating an OpenGL context, loading that extension, destroying the original context and creating a new one by calling `wglCreateContextAttribsARB (...)`. See the extension spec. I listed for more details.

---

#### When this extension is supported, calling

```c
    wglCreateContext (hdc)
```

#### Is equivalent to calling

```c
    wglCreateContextAttribsARB (hdc, 0, NULL)
```

Comment: Additional info: **not** explicitly requesting a version (the last paragraph _"is equivalent to..."_) has the non-authorative meaning _"most recent supported version which is backwards compatible with OpenGL 1.0"_. That is nowadays usually the 3.2 (Apple/Intel) or 3.3 (everybody else) compatibility profile. Unluckily, the wording is "should", so you cannot rely on that behavior 100%.

Comment: @Damon: That doesn't make any sense on Apple. If you don't request a context version in OS X, you always get 2.1. Intel's a little different though, Mesa doesn't support compatibility profiles so you usually get a 3.0 context if you don't request core.

Comment: Ah, Apple comes as a surprise for me, I was under the impression that they support 3.2 (and according to the spec, that's what they should "typically" return then). But well, I guess given the loose wording, anything they return is "correct".

Comment: @Damon: They do support 3.2, in fact they support up to 4.1 at the moment. But you can only get a 3.2 - 4.1 context if you request a core profile. You cannot actually request an explicit version on OS X, you either get a non-core profile (2.1) or a core profile (something between 3.2 and 4.1, whatever your hardware / operating system version supports).

Answer (score 1):

Nope, it's not defined. You need to ask for a particular version if you want any guarantees.

You can typically expect a Compatibility profile, though, because of the need for the legacy support.

Comment: That's not why you can expect a compatibility profile by default. It's so that old software from 15 years ago continues to run. If they suddenly changed the default behavior to give you a core profile, then most OpenGL software wouldn't run.

Comment: Well, okay, this might be a reason too